# unable to get response object

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am unable to get the response from api as the response is quite large. Below code gives internal server error but on rest client runs fine.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

[manager GET:constantString parameters: nil  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"POST data JSON returned: %@", responseObject);
    jsonArrayNew = responseObject;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];

}
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);             
     }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    });
});
```

Comment: What it your error ?

Comment: internal server error

Comment: please check your API into postman, If same error is there or not

Comment: already checked on rest client, it works fine but it takes some time to load the response

Comment: response is very large.. json array with around 3000 objects

Comment: it is AFnetworking 2.0 ?

Comment: what is your constantstring ?You  r using get method but in your nslog you write post data with json, So please change your webservice method to post and try it

Comment: yes AFnetworking 2.0 and constantString is the url of api

Comment: afnetworking 2.0 not allow https i think. so u need to check that. also u have to confirm ur REST method is it GET or POST. and if server requires any other header data in that request.

Comment: Show your constantString. Your request must be wrong